# Java Httpclient MultipartEntityBuilder in HTTPS parameter were empty in java 1.7 and above

Tags: java, tomcat, parameters, https, multipartentity

I am using HttpClient MultipartEntityBuilder below code used for file uploading and this is working in java all version if my URL is HTTP.

This program not thrown any error while running and working in java 1.6 version also in HTTPS.

Suppose if i changed my URL from HTTP to HTTPS this code is not working in java 1.7 and above. we are using CR signed SSL certificate.
I ran this program in java 1.7 also received empty parameters in tomcat server 6 & 7 so my application unable to login
also response is like

**"either enter username or authentication token"**

because of all the parameters were revived empty values in servlet.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class FileUpload {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                String desctiption = "Account ID: nagaraj_n@hotmail.com<br />" +
                "User ID: efef3516a398a2f4ab96b0ef319f13ad<br />";
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("username", "myusername");
        params.put("password", "mypassword");
        params.put("action", "create");
        params.put("description", desctiption);
        params.put("title", "Testing please avoid");
        params.put("description", desctiption);

           String line = "";
           String responce = "";
           Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

            try {
            HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
              HttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

              HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("**https**://myurl.com/api?");

              MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
              entityBuilder.addPart("Attachment_field", new FileBody(new File("/home/Attachment.html")));
              entityBuilder.addPart("Attachment_field", new FileBody(new File("/home/Attachment1.html")));

              for(Object param : params.keySet()){
                  System.out.println(param.toString()+" : "+params.get(param.toString()));
                  entityBuilder.addPart(param.toString(), new StringBody(params.get(param.toString()), "text/plain", Charset.forName( "UTF-8" )));
              }


              final HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
              httpPost.setEntity(entity);

              HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
              while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                  responce += line;
                  System.out.println(line);
              }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

    }
```

Thanks